# Auto renewbale subscription - In App Purchase implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I want to provide auto renewable subscription in my iphone app,  using this i want to provide Songs content.I have lots of categories for songs.

The user can subscribe to one category ( Love ) for 1Month / 2 Month / 3Month.
As such i want to provide subscription for all the categories.

So what is my question is Can i create auto renewbale subscription as

**1)  Love Songs - 1 Month / 2 Month / 3Month**

**2) Friendship songs - 1 Month / 2 Month / 3Month**

can i create as above for one single application?

Also i will add new categories in my web server?( Content is managed by the webserver )

Is that possible , pls let me know

Comment: Even I am facing the similar situation.Were you able to deliver this, how did it worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make seperate product id for each version of your song,like song1month,song 2monthetc.and use their product id,s to purchase that product,U can change the content in your weserver ,but it needs to be deliverd through the same product id.MKstorekit4 will give You a clear idea about how to use autorenewable subscriptions.
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/